# Where's the response's body using nodeJS request?

Tags: node.js, node-request

I'm implementing a simple app that simply sends some GET request to a nodeJS-express endpoint. This endpoint is returning just this:

```
router.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.status(500).send("Error message");
}
```

My app is using [request](https://github.com/request/request) to send the request like this:

```
request.get(BASE_URL)
    .on("error", err => {
        console.log(`ERROR: ${err}`)
    })
    .on("response", res => {
        console.log(`RESPONSE: ${res.statusCode} - ${res.body}`)
    });
```

But `body` is always `undefined`. I have tried to use:

```
.on("response", res => {
    res.on("data", () => {
        console.log(`RESPONSE: ${res.statusCode} - ${data}`)
    }
});
```

But the `data` is some byte array. I just want the string message, where it is and how can I get it **without using the [callback syntax](https://github.com/request/request#custom-http-headers)**?

Answer (score 0):

If You are using express you will need to inject the body-parser middleware for parsing the request body.

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body); //data  
})
```

Comment: Yes I already use this. The problem is somehow the '.on("response", ...)` syntax. If I use the `request.(options, callback)` one, the response.body contains the message!

Comment: if you are using the express you don't have to use the http syntax express makes it lot short

Comment: Express is in the backend. My question is about the client, using `request`.